# What's the difference between a virtual "default" destructor and an explicitly empty one?

Tags: c++, default, virtual, destructor

I have read many similar questions related to this (including this insightful one: [What's the difference between "= default" destructor and empty destructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27762221/whats-the-difference-between-default-destructor-and-empty-destructor)), but none have quite answered my particular case. Do they differ according to how they're implemented by the compiler? If this is being used as part of a shared library, what's the best way to make the code portable? I'm also wondering if both cases inline the destructor - I think they do, but I'm not sure.

Is there any difference between these two pieces of code?

```
// Case 1 
struct BaseClass {
     virtual ~BaseClass() = default;
     virtual void func (int a)  = 0;
     shared_ptr<BaseClass> next;
};

// Case 2
struct BaseClass {
    virtual ~BaseClass() {};
    virtual void func (int a)  = 0;
    shared_ptr<BaseClass> next;
};
```

Both return "false" when I check them with std::is_trivially_destructible::value, so I know they are both non-trivial.

Thank you.