# When to make a destructor defaulted using =default?

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor

Although using `=default` for constructors is clear for me (i.e. forcing the compiler to create the default constructor while other ctors exist), I still cannot understand the difference between these two type of destructors:

1. Those that use `=default`
2. Those that are not defined explicitly and generated by compiler automatically.

The only thing that comes to my mind is that the group-1 destructors can be defined as virtual, but group-2 is always non-virtual. So, is that the only difference between them? Is there any scenarios that the compiler is not generating the destructor, but using `=default` forces the compiler to generate it?

p.s. I have checked lots of Qs in stackoverflow, but none of them answers my Q. Here are some relevant questions.

1. [Difference between =default and {} ctos/destructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576055/how-is-default-different-from-for-default-constructor-and-destructor)
2. [Defaulting virtual destructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576055/how-is-default-different-from-for-default-constructor-and-destructor)
3. [Difference between =default and empty dtrs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27762221/whats-the-difference-between-default-destructor-and-empty-destructor)

**Edit 1:** [This Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56968443/explicitly-defaulted-destructor-disables-default-move-constructor-in-a-class) on SO, focuses on disabling the default move constructors, that can be considered as ONE of the items mentioned in the accepted answer.

Comment: Defaulting a virtual or pure-virtual destructor are the only two applicable cases I'm aware of.

Comment: `=default` is considered a user-defined destructor.  I'm wracking my brain trying to remember any behaviours that change if a class has a user-defined destructor vs no specified destructor. This sort of thing happens all the time with constructors, but I can't think of any for destructors.

Comment: The destructor itself behaves the same for `= default` versus omitting it; but the presence of the declaration suppresses implicit generation of the move-constructor and move-assignment

Comment: Those generated by the compiler implicitly will need complete types, which is not possible if you're making a `pimpl` class. You can then declare `~X();` and do `~X() = default;` in the implementation, after the `pimpl` type is complete.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: But how is `=default` distinct from `{}` in that case?

Comment: Other cases:  you wish to make it `protected` or `private`.  You wish to put it in a .cpp file so that it isn't inlined.

Comment: *'but the presence of the declaration suppresses implicit generation of the move-constructor and move-assignment'* – but if that should be the reason for writing it at all, then explicitly `delete`ing the move constructor and assignment is better choice...

Comment: I still don't see the difference between `destructor() { }` and `destructor() = default;` – I would suppose that defaulting the constructor is mainly for consistency reasons: One might have defaulted constructors and assignments already (possibly not all of them...). Then it simply looks better if the destructor follows the same pattern as the others...

Comment: @DavisHerring Afaik, there is no difference in the case I presented. I should have written: "_Those generated by the compiler implicitly will need complete types, which is not possible if you're making a `pimpl` class. You can then declare `~X();` and define `~X() = default;` or `~X() {}` in the implementation, after the `pimpl` type is complete._" to point at one possible diff between implicit and explicit.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Can you show that with a simple code snippet somewhere?

Comment: @Aconcagua I think the main difference is being trivial and non-trivial while using =default or {}, as mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13578720/896012

Comment: @Hoodi Take a look at the [widget](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl#Example) example.

Comment: @Aconcagua: A deleted move constructor or assignment operator participates in overload resolution (unless it is implicitly declared), which is not the same as not having one at all.

Comment: @DavisHerring Hm, overlooked the situation where we wouldn't want to delete *both*... But for the case we'd just wanted one of them providing the other one with `= default` again appears the better choice to me...

Comment: @DavisHerring I think this Q is more general that you have mentioned. The referenced Q, just focuses on disability of move move constructors, but as you have answered, there are other differences as well.

Comment: @Gupta: You’re right—I pasted the wrong link!  I can’t vote again (soon), but it should have been [this more general question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31672207/8586227) instead.  (I do still like my own answer.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(Several of the points below were already mentioned in comments or in the linked questions; this answer serves to organize and interrelate them.)

There are of course three ways to get a “simple destructor”:

```
struct Implicit {};
struct Empty {~Empty() {}};
struct Defaulted {~Defaulted()=default;};
```

Like a default (and not a copy or move) constructor, `{}` and `=default;` mean largely the same thing for destructors.  The interesting properties of `Defaulted` are then those (combinations) that differ from *both* of the others.

Versus `Empty` the main difference is simple: the explicitly defaulted destructor can be **trivial**.  This applies only if it is defaulted inside the class, so there is no difference between `{}` and `=default;` on an out-of-line definition.  Similarly, being virtual removes any distinction, as does having any member or base class with a non-trivial destructor.  There is also the distinction that an explicitly defaulted destructor can be implicitly *defined* as **deleted**.  Both of these properties are shared with implicitly declared destructors, so we have to find a distinction from those as well.

Versus `Implicit`, an explicitly defaulted destructor suppresses move operations, can be declared `private`, `protected`, or [`noexcept(false)`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1286r2.html), and in C++20 can be constrained (but not `consteval`).  Very marginally, it can be declared `constexpr` to verify that it would be anyway.  Declaring it `inline` doesn’t do anything.  (It can also be out of line or virtual, but as stated above that can’t be a reason to use it.)

So the answer is “when you want a trivial (or potentially deleted) destructor that has other special properties”—most usefully, access control or `noexcept` status.